# python import module with arguments

Tags: python

I have a module that defines some functions, and I want this module to import different package based on arguments.

For example, I now have a file called `my_module.py`:

```
if CUDA is True:
    import numpy as pkg
else:
    import cupy as pkg

print(pkg.__name__)
```

When I import `my_module` from another file, I expect to somehow add an argument `CUDA` such than when it's True, then `my_module` imports `cupy` and then prints out "cupy", otherwise import `numpy` and prints "numpy"

For example, this is my `main.py`:

```
import my_module # somehow add an argument CUDA=False, should print "numpy"
>>> numpy
```

Comment: You can't pass arguments, the syntax simply doesn't support it: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement. Typically this sort of thing is done by just trying to import the dependencies, and catching the error if they're not installed and falling back to the next one.

Comment: Consider using an environment variable? That's the right scope for what you're trying to do. `if os.environ.get("CUDA") is not None: ...`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have numpy and cupy installed, I simply want to choose whether `my_module.py` compute things in CPU or GPU. Is there a way?

Comment: As Adam suggests you could use an environment variable. I'd be inclined to make it semantic (`USE_GPU=true`) rather than tied to the implementation (`CUDA=true`).

Comment: Use a class. Instantiate the class with what u want

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this works for you

main.py:

```python
#main.py
import module

a = module.x()
b = module.x(True)
a.get_pkg()
b.get_pkg()
```

and

module.py:

```python
class x:
    def __init__(self, numbers=False) -> None:
        if numbers:
            import numbers as pkg
            self.pkg = pkg
        else:
            import string as pkg
            self.pkg = pkg
    def get_pkg(self):
        print(self.pkg.__name__)
```

the putput of python main.py will be:

```
string
numbers
```